# Writing php unit test in magento 2 issue

Tags: magento2, phpunit

This is my class:

```
class BillingAddress extends Template {
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function getCustomerFromSession()
    {
        $customerSession = $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
        return $customerSession->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

and this is my test class:

```
class BillingAddressTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var BillingAddress
     */
    protected $model;

    private function getSimpleMock($originalClassName)
    {
        return $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $context = $this->getSimpleMock(Context::class);
        $sessionFactory = $this->getSimpleMock(SessionFactory::class);
        //$this->objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);


        $this->model = new BillingAddress(
            $context,
            [],
            $sessionFactory
        );
    }

    public function testGetCustomerFromSession()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Customer::class, $this->model->getCustomerFromSession());

    }
```

When I run the test, I got this error message:

```
Error: Call to a member function getCustomer() on null
```

So how I can write a test for my method `getCustomerFromSession` to see, to check after the `instanceof` ?

Comment: any idea, how to approach this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
use Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;

class BillingAddressTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var BillingAddress
     */
    protected $model;

    private function getSimpleMock($originalClassName)
    {
        return $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $context = $this->getSimpleMock(Context::class);
        $sessionFactory = $this->getSimpleMock(SessionFactory::class);
       $this->objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);

       $this->model = $objectManager->getObject(
            BillingAddress::class,
            [
                'context' => $this->context,
                'customerSessionFactory' => $this->sessionFactory
            ]
        );
      
    }

    public function testGetCustomerFromSession()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Customer, $this->model->getCustomerFromSession());

    }
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the `Customer` into `Customer::class` and `$this->context` with `$context`.  Same with `sessionFactory`. But i still get the same error :|

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test, mock the customerSessionFactory's create method to return a customerSession mock, and then mock the getCustomer method of the customerSession mock to return the actual customer. Sample untested code:

```
$objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;($this);

$sessionFactoryMock = $this->createMock(SessionFactory::class);
$customerSessionMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
$sessionFactoryMock->method('create')->willReturn($customerSessionMock);

$customer = $objectManager->getObject(Customer:class, []);
$customer->setId(1)->setFirstname('John')->setLastname('Doe')->setWebsiteId(1);

$customerSessionMock->method('getCustomer')->willReturn($customer);
```